# Is Pitot Heat required for IFR?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules

CFR 125.205 states that

> § 125.205 Equipment requirements: Airplanes under IFR. No person may
> operate an airplane under IFR unless it has—  (a) A vertical speed
> indicator;  (b) A free-air temperature indicator;  (c) A heated pitot
> tube for each airspeed indicator;

but CFR 91.205 (d) (which describes the instrument equipment requirements for IFR (Instrument airworthiness), does *not* require pitot heat)

> (d) Instrument flight rules.  For IFR flight, the following
> instruments and equipment are required:
> (1) Instruments and equipment specified in paragraph (b) of this section, and, for night flight, instruments and equipment specified in paragraph (c) of this section.
> (2) Two-way radio communication and navigation equipment
> suitable for the route to be flown.
> (3) Gyroscopic rate-of-turn
> indicator, except on the following aircraft:
> (i) Airplanes with a third attitude instrument system usable through
> flight attitudes of 360 degrees of pitch and roll and
> installed in accordance with the instrument requirements prescribed in
> § 121.305(j) of this chapter; and
> (ii) Rotorcraft with a third attitude instrument system usable through
> flight attitudes of ±80 degrees of pitch and ±120 degrees of
> roll and installed in accordance with § 29.1303(g) of this chapter.
> (4) Slip-skid indicator.
> (5) Sensitive altimeter adjustable for barometric pressure.
> (6) A clock displaying hours, minutes, and seconds with a sweep-second >
> pointer or digital presentation.
> (7) Generator or alternator of adequate capacity.
> (8) Gyroscopic pitch and bank indicator (artificial horizon).
> (9) Gyroscopic direction indicator (directional gyro or equivalent).

So which is controlling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operations that are subject to U.S. [14 CFR **Part 91**.205(d)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/part-91#p-91.205(d)) do not apply to operations conducted under U.S. [14 CFR **Part 125**.205](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/section-125.205). These are two different CFR's (Part 91 and Part 125).

**Note**: 14 CFR Part 125 applies to airplanes having a seating capacity of 20 or more passengers or a maximum payload capacity of 6000 pounds or more.  [...] "Part 125 provides for the operation of large airplanes that are not conducting operations in **common carriage**...." (for example, "private carriage") (Ref: para 2.1.1 of [AC 125-1A](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_125-1A.pdf))

*(emphasis is mine)*

By the way, pitot heat is required under U.S. 14 CFR Part 91, Appendix A for Category II operations, (Group II instruments and equipment). See [Appendix-A-to-Part-91(2.)(b)(5)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/part-91#p-Appendix-A-to-Part-91(2.)(b)(5)). Group I and Group II have to do with instrument and equipment maintenance requirements.

Comment: Yes, after I posted the question, a friend called me and told me about this.... duh!  I should have known that...  Thanks!